# Add external module to python

Tags: python, python-2.7, fortran90

I want to read Fortran 90 binary files in Python and hence there is this module which has been developed for that in Scipy called as "fortranFile", as given here [fortranFile module](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/FortranIO/FortranFile)

How do I include this module in python so that I can call it from my code like

```
import fortranFile

f = fortranFile('file.bin')
x = f.readReals('f')

print x
```

right now, I get the error

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "readfortbin.py", line 5, in <module>
    from fortranFile import fortranFile 
ImportError: cannot import name fortranFile
```

I made a folder "fortranFile" in my /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages directory and added the 
"fortranFile.py" file to that folder. I know that I am missing something... Please suggest how I should proceed.

Comment: I think your problem is that it should be `from fortranFile import FortranFile`. I've added an answer below showing how to install the package from the PyPi package repository which has the added convenience of automatic updates when new versions are released.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry to bother again. I can import the module now, but It says "AttributeError: 'FortranFile' object has no attribute 'readReals'" though thats how the example code is implemented.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quickly address your question, I think your import statement is wrong. Specifically I think `from fortanFile import fortranFile` should be `from fortranFile import FortranFile`. It is  convention in Python is to capitalize every word in a class name.

On a different note there is a more up-to-date version of the module you're trying to install [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~nmb/fortranfile/trunk/view/head:/fortranfile.py) and in the [Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi). You can easily install it using the Python package installer `pip`.

**Important note:** `fortranfile` depends on the popular `numpy` numerical analysis package.

On my Ubuntu 13.04 system I had to perform the following steps:

```
apt-get install -y libpython-dev # For compiling the numpy C wrappers.
                                 # May alternatively be called python-dev or python-devel.
pip install numpy
pip install fortranfile
```

Comment: +1. I managed to install the fortranfile package, however, I am still getting the same error while using it. Thanks...

Comment: @arvind I think your import statement is wrong. If you installed the `fortranfile` package from `PyPi` using `pip` you should use the import statement `from fortranfile import FortranFile`. The second part of the import statement (a class name) has both words capitalized by convention.

Comment: Ah, I got it. Thanks for the help. The problem was in uppercase "fortranFile"